# Go build, with module, fails under an Alpine image but is fine under Windows

Tags: go, alpine-linux

I was running a small test to connect to ETCD. This test imports `go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3`
witch, by the magic of go modules, pulls `github.com/coreos/go-systemd/journal`.

I use **go module** to manage the dependencies.

First I ran my test under windows with `go version go1.13.1 windows/amd64` and everything is fine and works well as expected.

After that because my etcd client project is intended to be deploy via a Docker image, based on alpine, I tried to compile it with the go 1.13 image **golang:1.13-alpine**

I used :

```
docker run --rm -v "/${PWD}":/go/src/ -w //go/src/ golang:1.13-alpine go build -o etcd
```

I have faced a first known issue telling me that `git` was not installed on `golang:1.13-alpine`

> build github.com/nirekin/etcd: cannot load
>   github.com/coreos/go-systemd/journal: git init --bare in
>   /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/1f60ff15ab3093bffd86f4a985673d120db13dabca39c597aaa5016031c601a6:
>   exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH

Then I have built a new image, with the following docker file, in order to add `git` in `golang:1.13-alpine`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine

RUN apk --update add git less openssh && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

With my new image I have tried to compile again

```
docker run --rm -v "/${PWD}":/go/src/ -w //go/src/ my/image go build -o etcd
```

And I got this error:

> build github.com/myuser/etcd: cannot load
>   github.com/coreos/go-systemd/journal: no matching versions for query
>   "latest"

I cannot figure why the same version 1.13 of acts differently under **windows** and **alpine** at the moment of resolving dependencies?

Am i doing something wrong or missing something?

**File to eventually reproduce this strong text**:

**Go code**:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
)

func main() {
    c := clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   []string{"http://127.0.0.1:2379"},
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Printf("%v", c)
}
```

**go.mod:**

```
module github.com/nirekin/etcd

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/coreos/etcd v3.3.17+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/coreos/pkg v0.0.0-20180928190104-399ea9e2e55f // indirect
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.1 // indirect
    go.etcd.io/etcd v3.3.17+incompatible
    go.uber.org/zap v1.13.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.25.1 // indirect
)
```

Comment: Where is the mod-file that rererences systemd?

Comment: @Marcel I don't know, where/how can I locate it

Comment: this file references systemd https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/go.mod

Comment: Why build in a container rather than just building and copying the binary to the container? A Go app doesn't depend on Go at runtime.

Comment: @Adrian our whole CD/CI uses containers to build projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `go.etcd.io/etcd` depends on `github.com/coreos/go-systemd/journal` on linux, which is not using go modules correctly. There are two issues ([#321](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/issues/321) and [#325](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/issues/325)) submitted to the project and the maintainer acknowledge the problem (but not solved it yet).

The solution suggested there is to add the following to `go.mod`:

```
replace (
  github.com/coreos/go-systemd => github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22 latest
)
```

and then `run go tidy`. (inside container)